# DPLL time complexity analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, satisfiability, backtracking

Consider the most naïve backtracking for CNF-SAT. It only checks if an assignment satisfies the input formula $\phi$ when all the $n$ variables have values assigned. Let $m$ be the size of $\phi$. Then the time complexity for this backtracking is $O(m 2^n)$.

Now, consider DPLL. This algorithm is just a simple backtracking with some pruning strategy. Besides, DPLL simplifies $\phi$ along the backtracking, instead of doing it only at once, so the $O(m)$ cost is amortized. Hence, its running time should also be $O(m 2^n)$. Still, some places state that $O(2^n)$ is also an upper bound for DPLL (Wikipedia, for example). Does anybody knows the analysis to find this upper bound?

Comment: Why is $m=\Theta(n^k)$? That assumption is not correct, there are exponentially many possible CNFs with $n$ variables.

Comment: When talking about running time $n$ typically, and unless stated otherwise explicitly, represents the size of the input (not the number of variables).

Comment: Cook's theorem shows that $m = \Theta(n^k)$.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Give me any polynomial and I will give you a CNF where $m$ exceeds your polynomial.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. Just because you have shown that the algorithm is $O(n^k 2^n)$ does not mean that the algorithm cannot be $O(2^n)$. My understanding was that O is only the upper bound. A more clever complexity proof can prove better upper bound complexity results than your naive approach.

Comment: So please, show me that SAT backtracking is $O(2^n)$.

Comment: What research have you done?  Where have you looked?  Where did you read that DPLL's running time is $O(2^n)$?  What did they say to justify this?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking and to show us in the question what research you've done; this helps give you better answers, helps others who might run across your question, and incidentally sometimes enables you to solve your own problem yourself.

Comment: DPLL is a veeeery simple backtracking algorithm and I'm just asking if anybody here knows how to analyze it to show $O(2^n)$ upper bound. If you don't know the algorithm, just check wikipedia. That's all.

Comment: I'm asking that because the best analysis I can do is the one I wrote in the question. I really can't see how a backtracking that traverses a search space with size at most $2^n$, making so many simplifications to the input formula, can have an analytical upper bound of $O(2^n)$. That really makes no sense to me.

Comment: As you haven't really said where you're reading this, qualified who 'everyone' is, or listed any source for your claims, I'm going to assume your confusion is over a simplification in big O notation.

Assuming you're correct about the exact upper bound, for sufficiently large $n$, the term $2^n$ (exponential) dominates the $n^k$ (polynomial) term and so it can be left off when the important information is that this algorithm runs in exponential time, and the exact upper bound is not necessary.

Comment: Most likely, the bound on the running time should be understood as $\tilde{O}(2^n)$ rather than the strict $O(2^n)$. That is, we ignore polynomial factors.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. Thanks, JustAnotherSoul and Yuval.

Comment: @Kaveh, you're right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Well, what about $O(m 2^n)$? The $O(2^n)$ abuse is still reasonable? 'Cause $m$ may be much larger than $n$.